# how modify oncontextmenu in js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change an existing "oncontextmenu" of a div.

**The div:**

```
<td id="linetitle_title1" oncontextmenu="LoadLineXml('dGl0bGUx')">
```

**The js:**

```
var linekey = window.btoa(document.getElementById('updateTitle').value);
var linefunction = "LoadLineXml(\'"+linekey+"\')";
document.getElementById('linetitle_' + input ).oncontextmenu = linefunction;
```

Any idea for change it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `oncontextmenu` *property* accepts a function, but you'll probably also need to wrap that function in an IIFE to protect the scope of `linekey` depending on how that function is called:

```
document.getElementById('linetitle_' + input ).oncontextmenu = (function(key) {
    return function() {
        LoadLineXml(linekey)
    }
}(linekey));
```

Which is what you should be doing instead of setting attributes within HTML. You could set the *attribute* directly to override the attribute which is already there:

```
document.getElementById('linetitle_' + input ).setAttribute("oncontextmenu", linefunction);
```

But I wouldn't recommend that approach.

Comment: Oh ok thx.
I have another problem: my key is generated "on the fly" and implemented as a string, not a dynamic argument.
And this function seems to ask for a dynamic argument, right ?